# Nemo "open in Terminal" doesn't work in Ubuntu MATE 16.04

Tags: mate, filemanager, ubuntu-mate, nemo

I'm using Nemo file manager in ubuntu mate 16.04 LTS... but when i `Right click --> Open in Terminal`, nothing happens. not even error messages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out that Nemo is configured to launch `gnome-terminal`, so installing it fixes the issue:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal
```

Also you can [install it](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/gnome-terminal/) from Ubuntu Apps.

Comment: +1 for the info, but what about configuring it to launch `mate-terminal` instead? Seems a bit of a pain to have to install an extra emulator only for that purpose

Comment: @Zanna agree that optimal is launching the already installed terminal (`xfce4-terminal` in my case) rather than installing more stuff. However, installing the gnome terminal is not "such a pain": under 30s installation time with `synaptic` and under 3MB total disk space use... A piece of cake ;)

Comment: "install update"? I do not believe this is correct.  "sudo apt update", perhaps?

Comment: @ShefSam My bad, i will fix it.

Answer (score 8):

You can use gsettings to launch the MATE terminal:

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec mate-terminal
```

Comment: Works fine, indeed, but...I always wonder: where is this documented? I'd be glad to have a link!